# How can I use sha256 in stead of sha1 as Signature Algorithm? phpsecllib

Tags: sha1, sha256, phpseclib, sethash

On the samples page: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/guide.html there is a sample "Example: CA-signed cert" I have been playing with it, but whatever I do, I only get sha1 signatures. I tried to `setHash('sha256')`, but no luck. How can this sample code generate sha256 signatures?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check how you can change the algorithm to sha256?

Comment: Yes I did. setHash('sha256'), right? But wherever I put this, it stays sha1 in the certificate...

Answer (score 0):

```
$x509->sign($issuer, $subject, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption');
```

The `$issuer` private key needs to be an instance of RSA for that to work but that's how you'd do it.

It probably ignores the `setHash('sha256')` thing because (1) not all the hashes you can use with RSA have OIDs that X509.php knows about and (2) options available in RSA - like [PSS signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme) - aren't supported by X509.php and may not have OIDs defined by any IETF RFC and may not be supported by another other X509 implementation out there.